# Is there a way to install a2p on Ubuntu?

Tags: awk, perl

I need `a2p` to convert a bunch of `awk` scripts, but starting with Xenial the `perl` package does not come with `a2p` any more.

Where can I get `a2p` from?

Comment: Apparently it got dropped. How about using `perlbrew` (`sudo apt install perlbrew`) to set up a customized perl installation which includes `a2p`? A simple `perlbrew install stable` should do the trick and (especially) not mess with the system’s perl.

Comment: Install Virtualbox -> install 14.04 -> install a2p. Keep internet away from this install and you could use it for ages to come ;)

Comment: thanks @dessert , it sound goods, but isn't there any way to got only the script a2p  without  the whole perl distro ? I would like this solution to be evolving with my system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of `cpanm` from the `cpanminus` package I was able to install

```bash
cpanm App::a2p
```

which gives me the command `a2p` in my home.

You can also install it systemwide :

```bash
sudo cpanm -S App::a2p
```